# Accept only character and space in text box(edit control) in Win32

Tags: winapi

I don't know how to text box accept only character and space when we type to textbox.I just think we can use WM_Keydown but i just guess it cannot know which edit control we type in.
This is my code to create form

```
void CREATE_EDITNAMECONTROL()

Create_Control( hNameEditControl,   /* Handle */
    NULL,//NULL,        /* Handle of parent */
    L"Edit",  /* class name */
    ID_EDIT_CONTROl , /* ID     */
    L"",        /* Caption/Title */
    EDITCONTROL_STYLE, /* Style */
    200,        /* Position X */
    70,     /* Position Y */
    160,        /* Width      */
    30 );       /* Height     */
```

```
void CREATE_EDITDATECONTROL()
```

`Create_Control( hDateEditControl,   /* Handle */
    NULL,//NULL,        /* Handle of parent */
    L"Edit",  /* class name */
    ID_EDIT_CONTROl , /* ID     */
    L"",        /* Caption/Title */
    EDITCONTROL_STYLE, /* Style */
    200,        /* Position X */
    110,        /* Position Y */
    160,        /* Width      */
    30 );       /* Height     */`

Comment: The `key_down` event? Native Windows API does not use "events" like that in favour of messages. Can you update your question to state which framework you're using.

Comment: sr for that i just lear about win API.It's in WM_KEYDOWN

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a windows message in your `WndProc` you get the target window handle passed as `hWnd`. You can compare this value with the stored handle for each control to determine which triggered the event.

If it's the relevant edit control, you can then filter and change the text to suit.

Note that there are many way to change the text in an edit control that doesn't involve the `WM_KEYDOWN` message, for example, right click and paste.